# Multiple HTTP requests generated from Single HTTP request Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, httprequest

Backend API's:
url: http://www.sample.com/getAllPersons

```
[
    {
        "name": "ABC",
        "occupation": "Student",
        "address_url": "http://www.sample.com/address/person=hgjgjgyyfhg"

    },
    {
        "name": "ABC1",
        "occupation": "Carpenter",
        "address_url": "http://www.sample.com/address/person=fsdafdsa"

    },
    {
        "name": "ABC2",
        "occupation": "Developer"

    },
    {
        "name": "ABC3",
        "occupation": "Tester",
        "address_url": "http://www.sample.com/address/person=sgdfsgd"

    }
]
```

url: http://www.sample.com/address/person=hash_value

```
{
    "address": "XYZ",
    "city": "Phoenix",
    "state": "Arizona",
    "pin code": "3243242"
}
```

Need array of objects:-

```
{
    "name": "ABC",
    "occupation": "Student",
    "address": "XYZ",
    "city": "Phoenix",
    "state": "Arizona",
    "pin code": "3243242"

}
```

I need to show in a view the name, occupation and full address of every person with the above two api urls.
Note: Every person's address may not be available.

Please suggest the best method to do this asynchronously using HTTP Service and Promises/Observables in Angular 2.

My Solution:
Create http request promise of getAllPersons.
In then function:

- Save the response in a component class variable.
- Create array of http promises of every object's address_url (if it is present).
- Return Promise.all([Array of address url promises])

In then function:

- Iterate responses one by one and add them to the component class
  variable containing address_url.

Is there any better way? Also suggest if this was a three way hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatMap` and `forkJoin`:

```
var o = http.get('http://www.sample.com/getAllPersons')
    .flatMap(t=> Observable.forkJoin( 
            t.json().filter(x=>x.address_url != null)
             .map(y=> http.get(y.address_url).map(t=>json()))
     ));
```

Subscribe like this:

```
o.subscribe(arr=> {
   //arr[0] --> address_url[0]
   //arr[1] --> address_url[1]
   ...
});
```